# How do I properly re-install an OS to the same partitions after failing for the first time?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, 64bit

I have Ubuntu installed. I created 2 more partitions for Linux Arch and failed to install it due to choosing the wrong packages via package manager. It will work on my computer for sure (it already did). So I'm going to re-install it.

The reason I created 2 partitions (/boot and main /) for Arch is that I'm on UEFI system and it's x64 also. That's a must.

So do I have to remove all the files from these 2 partitions before re-installing Arch or can I just re-install it without it? If case I have to remove them, how would I do that? Just `mount` them (partitions) while I'm on Ubuntu and remove via `rm -r` all the files in them?

Comment: I would just re-create the partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably wipe and reformat those partitions.

Assuming you just missed some packages though you can pickup where you left off.

Boot the Arch livedisk mount the partitions and use archchroot to install the correct ones.  This is also a common strategy when you need to recover from driver or kernel problems.

Comment: Agreed. If there is no data on those partitions, wipe them and start over.

Comment: why not to a) mount them while I'm in Ubuntu and b) rm -r /mnt/parition/* ?

Comment: There's nothing terribly wrong with doing that, but if you're going to re install anyway you might as well just start over from the beginning with by reformatting those two partitions.

Comment: they are already formatted by Gparted. If I don't want to reformat them via gdisk or something else because it's kind of complex (there are other partitions as well and I don't want to remove them by mistake).

Comment: The bottom line is no you don't __need__ to reformat them. But you also don't need to do it with gdisk. Formatting them with Gparted would be fine, rm-ing everything on them would be fine. Typically when you re-install something, unless you're trying to recover or keep some part of it you reformat the effected partitions as it guarantees a good starting state, but it's not strictly speaking necessary.